Solutions of the multivariable congruence equation
Given a prime $p$ and integers $p>a_1, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1}>0$, I have to compute and store all the solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ of the following equation:
$$ a_1x_1 + \dots + a_nx_n = a_{n+1} \mod p $$
I know that this equation has $p^n$ different solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, but I want to know if there exists an efficient method to calculate the different solutions.
Thanks a lot.

I know that this equation has $p^n$ different solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. I don't think so. For example, take $a_{n+1}=1$ and $a_i=0$ for all $i\le n$. Then there are $0$ solutions.

Rather than $a_i > 0$ you probably want that $a_i$ is not a multiple of $p$.
